# How to update a view added in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What I'm doing?

I'm adding dynamic views to my `UITableViewCell` (which isn't subclassed).

Cell Hierarchy :

`UITableView` > `UITableViewCell` > `cell.contentView` > `MainView` > `([Number Of PointView] + [Options View])`.

Here it is:

[image]

When a user will tap  "Add Another Point", I'll add a PointView (which will be same as above) :

Y position `[     ]` X position `[     ]`

which will be look like this,

[image]

What is my logic to get this done?

- I'm taking `MainView` from `cell.contentView`.
- Then fetch last two views (Point View & Options View) added into `MainView`.
- Add Another `PointView` in `MainView`.
- Update frames for newly added `PointView` based on last `PointView` and also update frame of `OptionsView`.
- Resizing height of `MainView`
- And reloading particular cell.

I'm able to get it work, to confirm I've logged frame and subviews for that `MainView`. But once I tap on "Add Another Point" button again, I found that `MainView` isn't updated at all?

My simple question is, if I have a `MainView` (which I fetch from a Cell), can I update it directly or not?

P.S. I already have a *poor* solution for this is, to remove `MainView` and recreate new – which I found unnecessary. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes you can.

`cell.contentView` is a placeholder. What you are likely running into is an entirely different problem: `UITableViewCells` are cached, then recycled and reused by the system.

Anytime you respond to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you basically need to reset the content.

Comment: I'm using dynamic identifiers to create cell.

Comment: I think, that will be an ugliest solution "to populate content each time..." as I mentioned in my question, I already done this in that way but I don't think that was a good way!

Comment: **You have other options:** pass a unique identifier for each cell in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Doing so will prevent the OS from reusing your cells, and will also allow you to capitalize on previous changes you already made to that cell. Other cons include poor memory management scheme, which may not be an issue if you have a limited number of cells.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do. Just make this one cell class[image]

This one other cell subclass

[image]

Use this method to insert your rows and also update your data source for table view that is the number of rows in section part

Your **+ button** on click method can be like this..

```
//Use your own logic what you want to do.
Update your data source
NSIndexPath* index=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[table count]-1 inSection:0];

NSMutableArray* indexPathArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[indexPathArray addObject:index];

//index will be your new added point cell. Updating your    datasource

[_myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Make this YES

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've only put part of the cell. Actually, what I'm doing is resizing a cell height based on it content. All above things is actually will go for a single cell. However, this is not something that I'm looking for. There's a separate reason of using my own logic.

Comment: ok but this sort of logic can simplify things and you can have tag for every cell or for textfields and solve accordingly your problem.